# Javascript fullscreen with no morph transition effect?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, transition

Is there a way to use the javascript fullscreen capability without the default (ugly) morph effect?

This is the effect I'm talking about: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/fullscreen.php

Answer (score 0):

No. It's a browser behaviour, and the transition depends upon the browser.